# Is it possible to filter traffic using WFP (Windows Filtering Platform) while maintaining access via Winsock / SIO_RCVALL?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, udp, wfp

I'm writing a C++ application that uses WSAIoctl/WSARecv, passing the SIO_RCVALL flag to promiscuously intercept all traffic for the purposes of then statefully blocking traffic that does not meet certain criteria.

For the purposes of this example, the traffic should be thought of as UDP traffic on an arbitrary port, say 5000. The desired behaviour is to maintain monitoring capability while dropping the traffic from the perspective of other applications.

I've tried the following approach:

SIO_RCVALL matching rule?

```
    fwpFilter.layerKey = FWPM_LAYER_INBOUND_TRANSPORT_V4;
    fwpFilter.flags = FWPM_FILTER_FLAG_CLEAR_ACTION_RIGHT;
    fwpFilter.action.type = FWP_ACTION_PERMIT;
    fwpFilter.subLayerKey = GetSublayerKey();

    fwpFilter.weight.type = FWP_UINT8;
    fwpFilter.weight.uint8 = 0xF; // High weight
    fwpFilter.numFilterConditions = 1;
    fwpFilter.filterCondition = fwpFilterConditions;
    fwpFilter.displayData.name = const_cast<wchar_t*>(L"Allow Promiscuous");
    fwpFilter.displayData.description = const_cast<wchar_t*>(L"Support all traffic capture.");
    fwpFilter.flags = FWPM_FILTER_FLAG_CLEAR_ACTION_RIGHT; // Prevent BLOCK by other rules/layers?

    fwpFilterConditions[0].fieldKey = FWPM_CONDITION_FLAGS;
    fwpFilterConditions[0].matchType = FWP_MATCH_FLAGS_ALL_SET;
    fwpFilterConditions[0].conditionValue.type = FWP_UINT32;
    fwpFilterConditions[0].conditionValue.uint32 = FWP_CONDITION_FLAG_IS_RAW_ENDPOINT; // Match to raw socket with no further conditions
```

Traffic-specific rule:

```
    fwpFilter.layerKey = FWPM_LAYER_INBOUND_TRANSPORT_V4;
    fwpFilter.action.type = FWP_ACTION_BLOCK;
    fwpFilter.subLayerKey = GetSublayerKey();

    fwpFilter.weight.type = FWP_UINT8; // Medium Weight
    fwpFilter.weight.uint8 = 0xA;
    fwpFilter.numFilterConditions = 3;
    fwpFilter.filterCondition = fwpFilterConditions;
    fwpFilter.displayData.name = const_cast<wchar_t*>(L"Block specific");
    fwpFilter.displayData.description = const_cast<wchar_t*>(L"Port/IP specific block.");

    fwpFilterConditions[0].fieldKey = FWPM_CONDITION_FLAGS;
    fwpFilterConditions[0].matchType = FWP_MATCH_FLAGS_NONE_SET;
    fwpFilterConditions[0].conditionValue.type = FWP_UINT32;
    fwpFilterConditions[0].conditionValue.uint32 = FWP_CONDITION_FLAG_IS_RAW_ENDPOINT;

    fwpFilterConditions[1].fieldKey = FWPM_CONDITION_IP_LOCAL_PORT;
    fwpFilterConditions[1].matchType = FWP_MATCH_EQUAL;
    fwpFilterConditions[1].conditionValue.type = FWP_UINT16;
    fwpFilterConditions[1].conditionValue.uint16 = sourcePort;

    fwpFilterConditions[2].fieldKey = FWPM_CONDITION_IP_REMOTE_ADDRESS;
    fwpFilterConditions[2].matchType = FWP_MATCH_EQUAL;
    fwpFilterConditions[2].conditionValue.type = FWP_UINT32;
    fwpFilterConditions[2].conditionValue.uint32 = sourceIP;
```

Some strange behaviour can then be observed: once the rules are in place, the traffic is blocked from **all** applications while an application is bound to the local port. Upon unbinding, traffic is captured by the application using SIO_RCVALL as expected.

And to clarify, I **know** this is a less efficient and flexible approach to using callouts, but I'm attempting to avoid utilizing a callout driver **if possible**. If it's just flat-out not an option, I'll have to explore that route, but I thought I'd sanity-check before heading down that rabbit hole.

Comment: Reading of [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/tcp-ip-raw-sockets-2) leads me to believe this isn't possible: "Received datagrams are copied into all SOCK_RAW sockets that satisfy the following conditions". This implies the datagram has to actually make it through the network stack (e.g be received), which is not the case when you're blocking it for non-raw sockets. I don't know for sure, though, so I didn't post as an answer.

Comment: Does your filter work to filter the local port and the source IP once? Is `FWPM_CONDITION_FLAGS`, which seems to block all the traffic, necessary? There is a basic document sample [Permitting and Blocking Applications and Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/permitting-and-blocking-applications-and-users).

Comment: The intention was to set up a temporary filter to block traffic to a 3rd party process while maintaining an eye on the traffic to look for valid packets before removing the block.

From the looks of your suggestion @YangXiaoPo-MSFT, it seems like it would be possible to isolate the block to only affect specific processes, while leaving traffic delivery open to the wider network stack.

Comment: Yes, and you can also refer to these [wfp samples](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/27ffb0811ca761741502feaefdb591aebf592193/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/wfp) for more information.